# Determining average from database using VB6

Tags: sql, database, vb6

I’m trying to work out an average grade from a database file using the ‘Do Loop’ method; I’m completely clueless how to even start it. Does anyone have any tips or is able to help me?
Regards, Jack.

Comment: Why are you doing this in a loop and not in the database - will be much more efficient to run a SQL query to do this?

Comment: Sounds like homework... @Jack try showing us what you have at the moment and exactly where you're stuck and we can help further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than looping in vb, calculate the average in SQL.

E.g.,

```
select StudentID, avg(Grade) as AverageGrade
from StudentGrade
group by StudentID
```